# Output current max and over current threshold different?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, current-source

I'm new to electronic design.
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the output current max and over the current threshold in a power IC datasheet?(ex. LMZM33606)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter).

In this type of converter, in continuous mode, current in the inductor is a sawtooth (see Fig.4 in link above), whose average is the output current. So, for 6A average output current, maximum inductor current will be around 7-8A at the peak of the sawtooth, and it will have a minimum around 4-5A at the bottom of the sawtooth.

The chip has a fast current limiter to avoid damage in case of short circuit or inductor saturation. Because inductor current is a sawtooth, this current limiter cannot be set to the maximum **average** output current, because then it would trigger on every peak of the sawtooth. Instead it should be set a bit above the **peak** expected inductor current. In this case, if the maximum average current is 6A, maximum expected peak current around 8A, adding a bit of margin for tolerances and setting the current limiter to 9A makes sense.

The primary goal of this protection is to prevent inductor saturation. When an inductor passes too much current, its core saturates and its inductance drops which causes current to rise quickly, which accelerates the inductance loss, which accelerates current rise... it's a runaway process that ends with a blown MOSFET. Conduction losses in the MOSFET are proportional to current squared. A fast-acting overcurrent protection is required for the chip to be robust.

This protection also acts on output overcurrent, output short circuit, and can trigger on startup if output capacitance is large and the slow-start is set too fast.

Answer (score 0):

That [data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmzm33606.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1667754758181&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.digikey.co.uk%252F) says this about the overcurrent threshold: -

> 7.3.15 Overcurrent Protection (OCP) The LMZM33606 is protected from overcurrent conditions. Hiccup mode is activated if a fault condition
> persists to prevent overheating. In hiccup mode, the regulator is shut
> down and kept off for 10 ms (typical) before the LMZM33606 tries to
> start again. If an overcurrent or short-circuit fault condition still
> exists, hiccup repeats until the fault condition is removed. Hiccup
> mode reduces power dissipation under severe overcurrent conditions and
> prevents overheating and potential damage to the device. Once the
> fault is removed, the module automatically recovers and returns to
> normal operation.

So, if the output current rises past the specified maximum operating point of 6 amps to typically 9 amps (the overcurrent threshold) then the chip enters hiccup mode.

Answer (score 0):

The max output current is what the device can sustain, given appropriate operating conditions.

The overcurrent limit is where the device will shut down. For a switching regulator, this is the max current the FETs are allowed to deliver. You use this figure to size the inductor.

Continuous currents in between these two limits are not supported. So even though you could try to draw say, 8A, the performance (voltage, ripple, etc) isn’t guaranteed. Further, eventually the device will overheat and probably invoke thermal shutdown. Even then, the peak FET current will likely hit the threshold and cause a shutdown / restart cycle.